# Git meaning of '(Head -> Branch_Name)' and '(master)' in log

Tags: git

In a project I've not looked at in a while, the log message of the most recent commit is prefixed by `(Head -> Branch_Name)`. Further down the log messages `(master)` prefixes another commit message.

What do these message prefixes indicate, and what must have been done to get these messages? Note that `settings_handling` is the branch currently checked out.

```
817824881c (HEAD -> settings_handling) add: setting to order rows by title
e9235c269b docs: updated info. line documentation (fixing error)
68d3987fe0 add: various settings to control appearance
...skip a few...
ba9e71ee5f (master) refactor: WindowItem class overlay variables renamed
141d59b1aa add: OsWindowControl class; handles OS related window activity
```

When displaying the 'full' log these messages appear after the SHA checksum. e.g.

```
commit 817824881c67d71b49d27ab407fa460fbcbddfb6 (HEAD -> settings_handling)
Author: ******************************

    add: setting to order rows by title

    Setting added:
        order_rows_by_title (bool)
```

In case it is relevant, the current branch and status are:

```
$ git status
On branch settings_handling
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git branch
  master
* settings_handling
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names in parenthesis, such as `settings_handling` and `master` are branch names). The fact that you see `master` below `settings_handlings` means that this branch contains the `master` branch and adds commits to it. This could happen if you created it by branching out of `master`, or if you rebased it on top of `master`.

`HEAD` is a logical name that point to the last commit of the current branch, if you will. Since you're on the `settings_handling` branch, `HEAD` points to it.

Comment: I understand that they are branch names but why have these 2 commits been singled out?

Comment: These two commits are the tips (last commits) of these two branches, respectively. If, e.g, you'd create a branch from commit `e9235c269b` (e.g., by using `git branch new_name e9235c269b`), you'd see it on that commit too.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've just looked in some other projects and I'm getting these prefixes in all of them. I'm not used to seeing them hence the question - BUT I did a Linux 'upgrade' this morning (all software updated to the latest available version), and the log shows that git was updated. Clearly I've upgraded to a git version which shows these messages by default from a version that did not. Cheers.

Comment: `HEAD` is *not* the last commit; it is wherever you currently are. If you rat `git checkout master`, then `817824881c` would have just `settings_handling` in parentheses, and `ba9e71ee5f` would have `HEAD -> master`. The `->` means that `HEAD` logically points to that other branch; if you ran `git checkout ba9e71ee5f` you’d have a detached `HEAD`, and you’d see `(HEAD, master)` instead of `(HEAD -> master)`.

Answer (score 2):

You've already said it.

> Note that settings_handling is the branch currently checked out.

The message means means that `HEAD`, the commit currently checked out, is pointing to the `settings_handling` branch, which is pointing to commit `817824881c`.

Similarly, `master` is pointing to commit `ba9e71ee5f`, hence the annotation on that commit.